# Cannot make relation between composite key of primary key and foreign key

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have two tables:
"Projects", that have three (3) field. One composite key of two (2) fields: Donor_Source & Project_Number and Project title
[image: Project table design view]

Please note that Donor_Source field is indexed as Yes(Duplicates OK) and Project_Number field is indexed as Yes(No Duplicates).
It has to be this way because a donor can support multiple projects.

Lastly there is also the PRF_Table, it has many fields but since I want to relate it to the Project table, I made two fields that are used as foreign keys of Projects table:
[image: PRF_Table]

Please note that both fields of the foreign key are indexed as: NO.
As I was trying to relate the two tables, I managed to relate of project field from both tables but could not relate the donor source field of both tables:
[image: Relations between tables]

As can be seen from the picture above, I managed to get many:1 relation between PRF_Table & Project, which is correct. PRF_Table can have many records on a specific project, but that project is listed only once in the Project table

The problem rises when trying to relate the Donor_Source field: I always get indeterminate relation (something that I want to avoid). I guess the problem might be because the Donor_Source field in the Project table, although indexed, it still can have duplicates and it of course has duplicates in the PRF_Table.

What should I do in order to get many:1 relation (PRF_Table:Projects)?

Answer (score 0):

All fields in a *compound key* must be addressed to create *referential integrity*.

Thus, you must:

1. Create field Agrmnt_ID in PRF_Table and include that in the relation to the junction table.
2. Include field Donor_Source in PRF_Table in the relation to table Projects.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to create a field for `Agrmnt_ID` in your `PRF_Table` to have referential integrity.  What you are doing so far between `PRF_Table` and `PRF-PO_Junction_Table` is fine.

Regarding the link between `Projects` and `PRF_Table`, it appears that your intentions are for each record in `Projects` to be able to relate to multiple records in `PRF_Table`.  If so, then your solution is to change your Primary Key in `Projects` and consequently your relationship between the two tables.

1. In table `Projects`, remove your current composite Primary Key and create a single AutoNumber field (i.e. named `ProjectID`) as your Primary Key.
2. Now, in the `Projects` table, create your unique index on the `Donor_Source` and `Project_Number` fields (a composite, unique index), which will give you the same effect as your current composite Primary Key scenario, each Donor can be on multiple Projects, but the same Donor can't be on the same Project more than once.
3. Now, you will create the same field in `PRF_Table` that you created as your new Primary Key in `Projects` from step 1 (i.e. `ProjectID`)
4. Create your relationship between your new Primary Key in `Projects` and your new field in `PRF_Table`.  This will allow every Project/Donor record in `Projects` to have multiple records in `PRF_Table`.

Composite Primary Keys are most useful in junction tables, like how you are using one with `PRF-PO_Junction_Table`.  However, in any other link, you want try and have a single Primary Key field and use just a unique composite index to enforce uniqueness in two or more fields.